# Is there a setting I can add to Uploadifive to make pictures upload in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify, uploadifive

My application uses the Uploadifive jQuery plugin to allow clients to upload pictures. I upgraded it from Uploadify. It turns out that one client needs a feature that Uploadify had - pictures are uploaded to the server in the same order that they are listed on your computer.

Uploadifive doesn't have this feature. Pictures get uploaded in seemingly random order.

Is there a setting I can add to Uploadifive to make pictures upload in order? Or if not, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using 'simUploadLimit' : 1 in your configuration. This setting ensures that only one file at a time is processed. You lose out on simultaneous uploading, but, you gain in keeping your uploads in the order intended.